# Is it possible to schedule send an email using the default Mail OS app?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Most of the questions here are asked for the OS 2016 and before. It's 2020 now, are there any methods to schedule an email using the default mail app?

Comment: Just to clarify, did you want to send an email at a specified time and date, or like an auto-reply?

Comment: specified time and date, just like GMAIL does on their web app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mail doesn't have this feature out of the box but you can use your native Mac apps to schedule an email. My answer is based on macOS Catalina but it should be practically the same besides some minor differences, placement etc.

### Using Automator and Calendar:

1. Create an email workflow using Automator; then
2. Add the Automator workflow to a new Calendar event (formerly iCal)

#### 1. Create an email workflow using Automator

First open Automator app, which is found in the Utilities folder, and choose New Document. When you see the workflow type chooser, select Application.

Select Mail from the Library pane on the left, and a list of Mail actions will show in the Actions pane to the right. Scroll down and you will see the New Mail Message action. Double-click it or drag it to your workflow.

Once you've composed your message, add the Send Outgoing Mail action to the workflow. Now save the workflow and quit. Make sure the format is set as Application.

[image]

#### 2. Add the Automator workflow to a new Calendar event

Open Calendar app (formerly iCal) and choose New from the menubar, or select an existing event to edit.

Give the event a name and set the time and date as per usual. Where we can set an alert, we'll select Custom. From the dropdown, choose Open file, and from the next dropdown, (currently labeled Calendar) select Other. Now browse to the Automator workflow app from the previous step. Save the event and quit.

Should be good to go. Don't forget to keep your Mac turned on.

#### Edit: Using Calendar without a Automator workflow

The Calendar app lets you send an email as part of an events alert. Similar to the first method, instead of selecting Open file after choosing Custom for the alert type, you can select Email.

Not sure how long this has been an option or if its available in earlier versions of Calendar and iCal.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. This answers my questions due to no other way of scheduling an email by default. Unfortunately it's a hectic solution.

Comment: I noticed yesterday in the Calendar app, when choosing Alert > Custom, instead of selecting Open file, you could choose Email. Not sure if that was there on earlier versions of macOS/OS X but looks like it would skip the Automator step.

Answer (score 3):

It is now **2022** and MacOS will be getting this functionality at long last with MacOS Ventura as seen here: [New features available with macOS Ventura.](https://www.apple.com/macos/macos-ventura-preview/features/)

Under the Mac Mail section you'll see:

> Scheduled send: Schedule email to be sent at the perfect moment.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been absent in Apple Mail app for years, but Apple does not seem to care.

Asked on [Apple Discussions 2016](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7653730) with over 600 me toos.

[MailButler does this](https://help.mailbutler.io/help/how-do-i-schedule-an-email-with-send-later), but having to install a plugin for this is not a great solution as ideally this would natively be supported in Apples Mail client.